# Cannot set global variable inside a jquery function

Tags: jquery, function, global-variables

I simply am not able to set the global variable `purl` inside the following function so that I can retrieve it outside of it...

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(buttonClicked);
var purl;
function buttonClicked(tab){
    chrome.tabs.query({
        active: true,
        currentWindow: true
    }, function(tab) {
        //    console.log(tab[0]);
        window.purl= tab[0].url; // I even tried just 'purl= tab[0].url' 
        alert(purl); // This alerts the correct url !
    }); 
    alert(purl); //This alerts "Undefined" !
}
```

What is wrong ?

Comment: did you put this variable in document.ready function ?

Comment: @HamzaHaider The variable is defined inside a function in  background.js file of a chrome extension. Should functions also be wrapped in document.ready function ?

Comment: move it outside the function and then it will become global

Comment: Make sure if value is assigned to the variable before you alert it.

Comment: @HamzaHaider the variable is defined outside the function but a value is set inside the function.The value has to be set inside the function. I want that value to be available outside.

Comment: @Ajay value is set inside the function

Comment: Could you provide working example? Most probably undefined alert fired before value is assigned to the variable.